# Writing List To Text File

Tags: python, list, file-io

This is the end of my code:

```
duplicates = [files for files in file_dict.values() if len(files) > 1]

dupString = str(duplicates)

text_file.write("\n\n\nDuplicates Files: \n\n" + (dupString))
```

The output in the txt file is:

```
[['/Users/simon/Desktop/aF/file1.py', '/Users/simon/Desktop/aF/hidden/file2.py', '/Users/simon/Desktop/aF/hidden/file3.py']]
```

I want the output to be:

```
/Users/simon/Desktop/aF/file1.py
/Users/simon/Desktop/aF/hidden/file2.py
/Users/simon/Desktop/aF/hidden/file3.py
```

How can I make this happen? I tried using ' '.join(dupString) and '\n'.join(dupString) but it just made the string values have spaces or new lines in which wasn't what I wanted.

Comment: You want the quotation marks?

Comment: No Inbar, I don't need the quotation marks, I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it is my understanding that:

```
duplicates = [files for files in file_dict.values() if len(files) > 1]
```

Returns a list of lists of files. Your example being this:

```
[['/Users/simon/Desktop/aF/file1.py', '/Users/simon/Desktop/aF/hidden/file2.py', '/Users/simon/Desktop/aF/hidden/file3.py']]
```

In which case, what you need to do is first change that to make only a list of strings, you can do that with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
from itertools import chain
duplicates = chain.from_iterable([files for files in file_dict.values() if len(files) > 1])
```

Then it is just a matter of writing:

```
text_file.write("\n\n\nDuplicates Files: \n\n%s" % '\n'.join(duplicates))
```

Comment: That does it. Perfect. Thank you Inbar. I will do some reading into the itertools chain module.