# itertools ChainFromInterables Backslash Normalisation?

Tags: python, iterable

I posted a question a while back:

[Writing List To Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811131/writing-list-to-text-file)

I was able to write a list of files from a dictionary into a text file.

So my code looks like this:

```
simonDuplicates = chain.from_iterable([files for files in file_dict.values() if len(files) > 1])

text_file.write("Duplicates Files:%s" % '\n'.join(simonDuplicates))
```

This basically prints out directories and files, for example:

C:/Users/Simon/Desktop/myfile.jpg

The problem is the forward slashes. I want them to be backslashes (as used in Windows). I tried using `os.path.normpath` but it doesn't work

```
simonDuplicates = chain.from_iterable([files for files in file_dict.values() if len(files) > 1])

os.path.normpath(simonDuplicates)

text_file.write("Duplicates Files:%s" % '\n'.join(simonDuplicates))
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "duff.py", line 125, in <module>
    os.path.normpath(duplicates)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 402, in normpath
    path = path.replace("/", "\\")
AttributeError: 'itertools.chain' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

I think it doesn't work because I should be using iSlice?

Martijn Pieter's answer to this question looks about right:

[Troubleshooting 'itertools.chain' object has no attribute '__getitem__'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232132/troubleshooting-itertools-chain-object-has-no-attribute-getitem)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to apply `os.path.normpath` on [`chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable),
which returns a generator object. So, you have to iterate till the generator exhausts, to get the complete list of filenames which are of type string.

You can use list comprehension like this

```
simonDuplicates = [os.path.normpath(path) for path in chain.from_iterable(files for files in file_dict.values() if len(files) > 1)]
```

Or you can use [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function like this

```
simonDuplicates = map(os.path.normpath, chain.from_iterable(files for files in file_dict.values() if len(files) > 1))
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks. So the 'map' function basically turns the iterables (strings) into a list? and list's allow replace?

Comment: `map` function iterates through the generator object returned by `chain.from_iterable` and applies `os.path.normpath` to each and every element.